# alterar user-agent no webdriver selenium em python durante a navegação

Tags: python, mobile, selenium-webdriver, toggle, user-agent

preciso realizar o seguinte procedimento:

- 1) navegandor com user-agent mobile (eu consigo fazer)

  - abrir o site www.site.com e fazer login (eu consigo fazer)
- 2) alterar o user-agent para mobile(NÃO consigo fazer)

  - acessar uma opção no www.site.com que só aparece se mudar para mobile depois de fazer login(daqui em diante eu consigo)

Pois bem, a minha dificuldade é conseguir alterar o user-agent para uma opção mobile já com a sessão do webdriver aberta e em andamento.
Por exemplo, se fosse fazer isso na mão, seria abrir o DevTools com o "Ctrl+Shift+I" e depois um "Ctrl+Shift+M", e pronto, muda para mobile

Mas no python, para o selenium eu só encontro instruções para inciar a sessão webdriver em mobile desde o inicio da execução. Mas para este site em especifico eu tenho que fazer login em modo Desktop, e só depois alterar para mobile.

Não precisa me dar o código "mastigado", se pelo menos tiver alguma dica do que eu tenho que pesquisar para aprender e então implementar no código já ajuda.

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Navega com user-agent mobile  mas não alterar o user-agent para mobile

Poderia usar o radom para cada interação alterar.

import random

user_agent_list = ["Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; de-de; GT-I9300 Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30",
"outros agent"]

[User agents Android](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/android-browser/)

user_agent = random.choice(user_agent_list)

headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

print(headers)

A não ser que deseja alterar a configuração do browser para algum dispositivo mobile,é possivel usando o teclado basta adicionar as letas assim como o exemplo de abrir uma nova aba no navegador.